# How to pass a function an object and a property

Tags: javascript

I want to create the following method:

```
  // expects: (array of objects, name of property on object to compare
              to value, value to compare to)
  // returns: index of object in array
  function findIndex(array, delegate, value) {  
    for (index in array) {
      if (value === array[index].delegate) {
        return index;
      }
    }
  };
```

The above method does not work if I pass in a delegate value that is a string. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), like so

```
if (value === array[index][delegate]) {
   return index;
}
```

Comment: Oh verrrry cool! Thank you for this! I didn't know that existed. Worked like a charm!